# How to subtract 30 days from the current date using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am unable subtract 30 days from the current date and I am a newbie to SQL Server.

This is the data in my column

```
date 
------------------------------
Fri, 14 Nov 2014 23:03:35 GMT
Mon, 03 Nov 2014 15:18:00 GMT
Tue, 11 Nov 2014 01:24:47 GMT
Thu, 06 Nov 2014 19:13:47 GMT
Tue, 04 Nov 2014 12:37:06 GMT
Fri, 1 Nov 2014 00:33:00 GMT
Sat, 5 Nov 2014 01:06:00 GMT
Sun, 16 Nov 2014 06:37:12 GMT
```

For creating the above column I used `varchar(50)` and now my problem is I want to display the dates for past 15-20 days from the date column  can any one help with this issue ? 
update [ how can i display last 7 days dates in order

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you want to store dates, use `DATE`, or `DATETIME2(n)` - but most certainly **NOT** a `varchar` column!

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can convert it to `datetime`, and then use `DATEADD(DAY, -30, date)`.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

**edit**

I suspect many people are finding this question because they want to substract from current date (as is the title of the question, but not what OP intended). The comment of munyul below answers that question more specifically. Since comments are considered ethereal (may be deleted at any given point), I'll repeat it here:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Simple and brilliant!

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can swap DAY in the method with MONTH to do the same for a month differential. I'd imagine any valid datetime value would work.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
SELECT      GETDATE(), 'Today'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(DAY,  10, GETDATE()), '10 Days Later'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(DAY, –10, GETDATE()), '10 Days Earlier'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(MONTH,  1, GETDATE()), 'Next Month'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(MONTH, –1, GETDATE()), 'Previous Month'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(YEAR,  1, GETDATE()), 'Next Year'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(YEAR, –1, GETDATE()), 'Previous Year'
```

Result Set:

```
———————– —————
2011-05-20 21:11:42.390 Today
2011-05-30 21:11:42.390 10 Days Later
2011-05-10 21:11:42.390 10 Days Earlier
2011-06-20 21:11:42.390 Next Month
2011-04-20 21:11:42.390 Previous Month
2012-05-20 21:11:42.390 Next Year
2010-05-20 21:11:42.390 Previous Year
```

Answer (score 7):

TRY THIS:

Cast your VARCHAR value to DATETIME and add -30 for subtraction. Also, In sql-server the format **Fri, 14 Nov 2014 23:03:35 GMT** was not converted to DATETIME. Try substring for it:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -30, 
       CAST(SUBSTRING ('Fri, 14 Nov 2014 23:03:35 GMT', 6, 21) 
       AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-30,date) AS before30d 
FROM...
```

But it is strongly recommended to keep date in datetime column, not varchar.