# Why do I get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" when subtracting a number from GETDATE()?

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrect here.   I have the following values for these variables.

```
my $sql =  qq~
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tableName u
  WHERE 1=1 AND u.ManufacturerPartNumber IN ('X','Y','Z')
  AND CAST(u.InspectionStartDate AS DATETIME) > (GETDATE() - ?)
~; 
my $argsRef->{lookBack} = 30;
```

And when I try to run a `selectrow_array` on the sql like such:

```
my $qnCount = $dbh->selectrow_array($sql, undef, $argsRef->{lookBack});
```

I get the following error:

```
DBD::ODBC::db selectrow_array failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL-22007) [for Statement "
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM tableName u
 WHERE 1=1 AND u.ManufacturerPartNumber IN ('X','Y','Z') 
 AND CAST(u.InspectionStartDate AS DATETIME) > (GETDATE() - ?)
 "]
```

So, it is my understanding that the third parameter in the selectrow_array call from a database handle should be the bind variables.  Yet, they seem not to be binding....

the database handle is created as such:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect_cached("dbi:ODBC:$dsn", undef, undef, {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
    ShowErrorStatement => 1,
    LongReadLen => 500000,
})
```

`$dsn` is the correct DSN but not shown for various reasons, but we know it works due the error message coming back from SQL Server.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I assume the query should be `(GETDATE() - 30)`; placeholders are quoted by default, so you're actually getting `(GETDATE() - '30')`. Look at the section "Data types for placeholders" in the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#bind_param) and the [DBD::ODBC docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC#Binding-Columns).

Comment: Well, start by [using `DATEADD()` instead of shorthand](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx). Also the part about the $dsn and connecting to the database was copied from a different question and is not relevant here.

Comment: This does not look like an issue with Perl or DBI, rather your date query does not look right. Consider using `dateadd` to subtract days from `getdate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247770/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-date-using-sql-server

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I guess I assume that the DBI would be able to figure out whether to quote or not because the variable, but that probably isn't clear here.   I was attempting to use the bind such that it would cut down SQL injection.  Is there a way to place that value in there without worrying about SQL injection?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Thanks for the DATEADD() advice, I will give it a shot.   Not sure where I copied the DSN stuff from, considering I typed it in.   The reason I added it was just in case the database handle was the problem.   But it appears that is not the case.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Apparently T-SQL lets you subtract a number from a datetime and it subtracts that number of days: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189518.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Sure, but [that doesn't mean it's a good idea](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: @FrankRalphBob *"I assume that the DBI would be able to figure out whether to quote or not"* That depends on your version of DBD::ODBC and which driver you're using, among other things. See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC#odbc_default_bind_type

Comment: Ok, folks let's try to keep things constructive here. If you want to continue this conversation, then please take it to chat.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks but I don't think I'll get a better answer out of him in chat.

Answer (score 2):

First, a shout out to ThisSuitIsBlackNot for pointing out that the problem.   I made the assumption that the DBI/driver would be able to determine the value type.  That was wrong.  So, I explicitly stated the type:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bind_param( 1, ($argsRef->{lookBack} * -1), { TYPE => SQL_INTEGER });    
$sth->execute();
my $qnCount = $sth->fetchrow_array();
```

This allowed it to go through as an integer and the SQL ran without problem.

In case you were wondering why I am multiplying by -1, is because I changed the query to use DATEADD:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableName u
WHERE 1=1 AND u.ManufacturerPartNumber IN ('x') 
AND CAST(u.InspectionStartDate AS DATETIME) > DATEADD(dd, ?, GETDATE())
```

Although there seems to be some continuing discussion in regards to its use, it is working here.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I would also suggest `DAY` instead of `dd`, just to be more descriptive. Nobody is going to assume `dd` means `month`, but try out `y` vs. `YEAR` and `w` vs. `WEEK`. Another case where a few keystrokes pay huge dividends.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Good to know.   Thanks Aaron.   Unfortunately, my SQL Server knowledge still has a way to go - but always good to improve it.