# How to get 30 days before data from current date. How to take two date one date from session and next data (session+30) in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I want to take only two date one date from current login(session) and next date (current+30) in between operator.

WHERE "
                                                    "`it_service_ticket`.`request_date` BETWEEN ? AND ? "

first ?="current time"
second ?="current time" +30 days

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(1, new Date(session.getCreationTime()));
pst.setDate(2, new Date(session.getCreationTime())-30);
```

how to possible

Comment: Try `BETWEEN now() AND date_add(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247770/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-date-using-sql-server/27247821#27247821

Answer (score 1):

probably you are looking for `DATE_ADD()` function like

```
WHERE `it_service_ticket.request_date`
  BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Comment: when I take this query isn't running: WHERE  `it_service_ticket`.`request_date` BETWEEN 'NOW()' AND 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'

Comment: what you mean by that? you getting any error or what? post the error message in case any